# Android: Media player, Significance of context?

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player, android-context

In the following code:

```
MediaPlayer song= MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.whatchatalkin);
    song.start();
```

I understand that `Splash.this`is the context as i seen it in tutorial, however I dont fully understand what a context is, is it basically a reference to the class/activity you want to use it in?

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference to everything needed by the activity, fragment or application.  Various widgets, classes and methods need the context to know stuff in it.

From the Android docs:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.